# Redirecting with nginx accel headers

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers

Is it possible to download a remote file using nginx accel headers? I'm getting file not found in Firefox and invalid response in Chrome.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= 'asd.zip'");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('X-Accel-Redirect: http://subdomain.samedomain.com/upload/files/qwe.zip');
header("X-Accel-Buffering: yes");
header("X-Accel-Limit-Rate: 102400");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a proxy_pass to proxy to the remote server. Example:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= 'asd.zip'");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('X-Accel-Redirect: /upload/domain.com/path/to/file.zip');
header("X-Accel-Buffering: yes");
header("X-Accel-Limit-Rate: 102400");
```

Nginx

```
location ~* ^/upload/(.*?)/(.*) {
    internal;
    set $download_host  $1; 
    set $download_uri   $2; 
    proxy_pass http://$download_host/$download_uri;
}
```

Comment: The remote server is dynamic

Comment: Use regex to get the host.